# Checking for if is_off in template tag but ischange is not detecting change

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to hide a comment in a field if the employee is off. I have added my if tag to the field itself but in the `ifchange` loop it doesn't see the change and add a comment in the field if the employee is on. I've move this above the `ifchange` but then it will not show any fields if the employee is off. So basically my check skips the first one(off hours) but then the if_changed ignores the second one as the bar_record is the same. I can't figure out the way to work this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I got this fixed by moving the `if not foo.is_off` up the DOM but I was told this can be shorter. The `if` that is.

**CODE**

```
    {% for foo in bar_information.bar_hours %}
      {% if not foo.is_off %}   <!-- is there a shorter better way of writing this?  -->
      {% ifchanged foo.bar_record %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'rowEven' 'rowOdd' %}">
        <td>
          {{ foo.bar_record.get_formatted_id }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ foo.bar_record.entered_in|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT" }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ foo.bar_record.get_display }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ foo.bar_record.get_mistake_display }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {% if foo.bar_record.number_shifts %}
            {{ foo.bar_record.number_shifts }}
          {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="width: 400px; word-wrap: break-word;">
              {{ foo.bar_record.comments }}   <!-- THIS COMMENT IS WHAT I NEED TO HIDE IF EMPLOYEE IS OFF  -->
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
          <a class="button"
            href="{% url 'bar_record_view' foo.bar_record.pk %}">
                      View Record</a>
          {% has_permission_cust CHECK_COMPLIANCE %}
            {% url 'check_compliance' foo.bar_record.pk as check_compliance_url %}
            <a href="{{ check_compliance_url }}" class="button">Check Compliance</a>
          {% end_has_permission_cust %}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endifchanged %}
      {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: How is foo.bar_record being changed in each loop iteration? If it isnt being changed ifchanged will always answer false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that moving the 'if not foo.is_off' up the DOM it worked. As this:

```
{% for foo in bar_information.bar_hours %}
  {% if not foo.is_off %}   <!-- is there a shorter better way of writing this?  -->
  {% ifchanged foo.bar_record %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'rowEven' 'rowOdd' %}">
    <td>
      {{ foo.bar_record.get_formatted_id }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ foo.bar_record.entered_in|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT" }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ foo.bar_record.get_display }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ foo.bar_record.get_mistake_display }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {% if foo.bar_record.number_shifts %}
        {{ foo.bar_record.number_shifts }}
      {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 400px; word-wrap: break-word;">
          {{ foo.bar_record.comments }}   <!-- THIS COMMENT IS WHAT I NEED TO HIDE IF EMPLOYEE IS OFF  -->
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <a class="button"
        href="{% url 'bar_record_view' foo.bar_record.pk %}">
                  View Record</a>
      {% has_permission_cust CHECK_COMPLIANCE %}
        {% url 'check_compliance' foo.bar_record.pk as check_compliance_url %}
        <a href="{{ check_compliance_url }}" class="button">Check Compliance</a>
      {% end_has_permission_cust %}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endifchanged %}
  {% endif %}
{% empty %}
{% endfor %}
```